# How should I send/receive a large search results array (NodeJS, AngularJS)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, http, search

I have an app that uses NodeJS for the back-end and AngularJS for the front-end. When I send a search query using Angular's $http to my back-end, the back-end returns an array of search results.

I've discovered by testing my app on a remote server that a slow internet connection can really bottleneck the search. In particular, Angular can't use the search results until all of them are sent. This is okay for a small number of results (< 1,000) but I'd like to improve it for when there are many search results.

Is there a strategy I can use so Angular can display each search result as it arrives and not wait for the entire array to be sent?

Comment: What about pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would use websockets to send results one at a time (don't know why you would do that, check no. 2).
2. I would paginate the result on the backend to a reasonable amount (50 might do the trick depending on your loaded relationships) and implement an infinite scroll that fetches the next items asynchronously (something along the lines of https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

There is two necessary point:

1. Pagination: you should split the result array and send back just the first X result at first. If the user is interested about the others, send back more. I'm sure, there are a `skip` and a `limit` in your ORM, use those!)
2. Compress the data. I suggest to use Google [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for this.